# Downloading a file placed on SharepointOnline created via Power Automate to a linux folder (or unc share)

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Can someone please advise if we can download files from SharePoint Online daily as a batch job through shell script? Here is the context:

A windows automation process creates a CSV file at 6:00 AM on Sharepoint online. This csv needs to be loaded in a system hosted on RedHat Linux (on-premise).

One of the consultants is telling us that file copy is not possible and the only way to do is to have a Microsoft Data Gateway set up on a Windows server which will push this file to a windows server. Then use a powerrhell script running through task scheduler on windows to copy this file to the UNC share ( which is a Linux folder in reality).

As you would see, there are multiple hops being created and I was looking to simplify this, and check the possibility whether shell script (scheduled through control M) can be used to download that file. I am sure this situation might be common and so, I wanted to check if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the `PnP.PowerShell` module on Linux to directly connect to and download the file from SPO, or you could leverage the Data Gateway which can also directly copy the file from SPO to the on-prem Linux server (provided Samba is configured appropriately).

If you go the module route, I'd recommend you connect with Client ID + Cert.